# modsecurity block google bots [ Sitemap 403 error (Forbidden) ]

Tags: mod-security

I am submit sitemap on google webmaster tool google bots can't read my site.

> Error

webmaster tool: http://prnt.sc/dh6qje
modsec_audit.log: http://prnt.sc/dghx2n

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove modsecurity_crs_55_marketing.conf from your activated rules directory folder.

This seems a very odd set of rules to have turned on! Didn't even know they existed in CRS tonne honest as never seen them on before. Perhaps meant for sites you don't want indexed? It's an optional set of rules anyway, rather than part of base recommended core rule set and it does say at the top:

```
# These rules do not have a security importance, but shows other benefits of 
# monitoring and logging HTTP transactions.
# --
```

If you cannot remove from that directory (because you do not have direct access to the server for example), then you can turn them off by adding the following config to Apache:

```
SecRuleRemoveById 910006
SecRuleRemoveById 910007
SecRuleRemoveById 910008
```

Not these must be specified in the Apache configuration AFTER the loading of this modsecurity_crs_55_marketing.conf file.